# sql oracle todate differences

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Can someone please explain to me why the output for Query 4 is different to the others when query 1 returns the replaced values used in query 2 which should equate to running the same as query 4?

I suspect it's something to do with the nls_date_format however I'm not sure.

Query 1

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY')FROM DUAL;
TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MON/YYYY')
------------------------------
02-SEP-15
```

Query 2

```
SELECT TO_DATE('02-SEP-15') - TO_DATE('01/JAN/07') FROM DUAL;
TO_DATE('02-SEP-15')-TO_DATE('01/JAN/07')
-----------------------------------------
                                     3166

SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YY') - TO_DATE('01/JAN/2007') FROM DUAL;
```

Query 3

```
TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MON/YY')-TO_DATE('01/JAN/2007')
---------------------------------------------------
                                               3166
```

Query 4

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY') - TO_DATE('01/JAN/2007') FROM DUAL;

TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MON/YYYY')-TO_DATE('01/JAN/2007')
-----------------------------------------------------
                                              -72732
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never call `to_date` on a `date`.

Assuming your `nls_date_format` is set to "DD-MON-RR", which is what it appears to be based on your first query, when you run `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY')` the following happens.

1. `to_date` doesn't accept a `date` as a parameter, it only takes a `varchar2`.  So Oracle has to do an implicit cast from `date` to `varchar2` using your session's `nls_date_format`.
2. That transforms the call to `to_date( '02-SEP-15', 'DD/MON/YYYY' )`
3. Since your string input parameter has a 2 digit year but your format mask specifies a 4 digit year, you get a very unexpected result.  Rather than being interpreted as 2015, it is interpreted as the year 15 (2000 years ago when the Roman Empire was a thing).
4. Now you subtract a 2007 year from a 0015 year and you get a difference of just over 1,991 years (727,321 days to be exact).

The moral of the story-- never call `to_date` on a `date`.  It's already a `date`.  Converting it to a `date` makes no sense.  If you just want to set the time portion of a `date` to midnight, use `trunc`.  Don't cast a `date` to a `varchar2` back to a `date`.

Comment: Only after testing this with alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - TO_DATE('01/01/2007') FROM DUAL;
did it click that query1 would have actually returned '(00)15 in the year and by altering the nls date it wouldn't be a fair comparison in that it would 'show me more' as the conversion is entirely different. I did realise it wasn't the best query to be using, I just couldn't differentiate between the returned types.